# Variable initiation in Java

Tags: java, variables, initialization

In the below script, a new object called `setup` is created from the class `ScriptSetup`.

Then two variables are initiated. I really don't understand the logic in these two lines of code.
Why is the class `IntegerSetupType` in brackets before the new object `setup`? What does this do? 
The method `retrieveValue`, is it calling the class `ScriptSetup`? What about the method `resolve`?

```
private final String FILE_SIZE_SETUP = "file_size";
private final String DELAY_TIME_SETUP = "delay_time";

ScriptSetup setup = new ScriptSetup();
int fileSize = ((IntegerSetupType)setup.retrieveValue(FILE_SIZE_SETUP)).resolve();
int delayTime = ((IntegerSetupType)setup.retrieveValue(DELAY_TIME_SETUP)).resolve()
```

Comment: "*I really don't understand the logic in these two lines of code.*" - Why not ask the author? --- "*Why is the class 'IntegerSetupType' in brackets before the new object 'setup'?*" - This is called a [type cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Looks like `ScriptSetup` class has at least `retrieveValue` method in it. Now, we are not sure what `retrieveValue` is returning unless you show it. It must be returning either `IntegerSetupType` or it's parent type. And `IntegerSetupType` or it's parent has `resolve` method which returns an `integer`

Comment: About the type cast....that's helpful. Why do I need this here for the 2 variables?

Comment: They are not casting `setup` but the return type of `retrieveValue` method

Comment: So it will compile--it's likely `retrieveValue` returns an object, and if you want that as an `int` you need to cast it. Here's the thing: we have no idea what API you're using, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: @NathanHughes Or both! Oh wait, you said `||` so that works.

Comment: All that retrieveValue is doing here, is going to a user table and grabbing the entries for file_size and delay_time

Comment: Still don't understand why we need to cast these values from the user table

Comment: I can't guess anymore. if you want a proper answer, update your question will all methods and their return types

Answer (score 0):

The class 'IntegerSetupType' in brackets before the new object 'setup' is a Java feature called [type casting](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting). In your code, this is a way of extending ou narrowing the methods and properties available to the object returned by the method 'setup.retrieveValue()'. Casting is used with types that belong to the same class hierarchy (superclasses or subclasses) ou when you use interfaces and polymorfism.

The method 'resolve' belongs to the type IntegerSetupType.